# Create a openGl context (new version)

Tags: windows, winapi, opengl

i was trying to create a win32 that could handle openGl ( the new version). It doesnt seem to be mutch info about win32/opengl(new version, most examples are in the old version ) on the net.
The few info that i found lead me to this code. But it doesnt display the square.
Does any one know if this is the proper way to do it, and if so what is wrong with it(it doesnt display square).
Ps. i know that the part of the vbo, vao ,shader.. are working cause i already did that with sdl.

Thank a lot.... :)

Here is the Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <glew.h>
#include <wglew.h>

using namespace std;

void display(){
// display square
}

bool progRun = false;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
//#####################################################################
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    int       nCmdShow
){
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    ///////////////////////////LOAD GLEW///////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC | CS_DBLCLKS ;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = NULL;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,"RegisterClassEx","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP);
        return 0;
    }
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
                    szWindowClass,
                    szTitle,
                    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                    500, 500,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    hInstance,
                    NULL
                    );

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,"hWnd","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP);
        return -1;
    }
    HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;

    memset(&pfd, 0, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR));
    pfd.nSize= sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    pfd.nVersion   = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags    = PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 32;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 32;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    int pf = ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd);
    if(pf == 0){
        MessageBox(NULL,"pf == 0","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP);
        return -1;
    }
    if(SetPixelFormat(hdc, pf, &pfd) == false){
        MessageBox(NULL,"SetPixelFormat","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP);
        return -1;
    }
    DescribePixelFormat(hdc, pf, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR), &pfd);

    HGLRC hrc = wglCreateContext(hdc);
    wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc);

    glewExperimental = true;
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK){
        MessageBox(NULL, "Couldn't initialize GLEW!", "Fatal Error", MB_ICONERROR);
    }
    wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
    wglDeleteContext(hrc);
    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
    ///////////////////////////////TO_CREATE A OPENGL CONTEXT WITH LATER VERSION///////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    #define iMajorVersion 3
    #define iMinorVersion 1
    hWnd =  CreateWindow(
                    szWindowClass,
                    szTitle,
                    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                    500, 500,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    hInstance,
                    NULL
                    );
    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,"hWnd","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP);
        return -1;
    }

    hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
    bool bError = false;

    if(iMajorVersion <= 2)
    {
        cout << "version 2" <<endl;
        memset(&pfd, 0, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR));
        pfd.nSize       = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
        pfd.nVersion   = 1;
        pfd.dwFlags    = PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW;
        pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
        pfd.cColorBits = 32;
        pfd.cDepthBits = 32;
        pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

        pf = ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd);
        if (pf == 0){
            MessageBox(NULL,"pf == 0","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP);
            return false;
        }

        if(!SetPixelFormat(hdc, pf, &pfd)){
          MessageBox(NULL,"SetPixelFormat 1","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP);
          return false;
        }

        // Create the old style context (OpenGL 2.1 and before)
        hrc = wglCreateContext(hdc);
        if(hrc)wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc);
        else bError = true;

    }
    else if(WGLEW_ARB_create_context && WGLEW_ARB_pixel_format)
    {
        cout << "version 3" <<endl;
        const int iPixelFormatAttribList[] =
        {
            WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB, GL_TRUE,
            WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB, GL_TRUE,
            WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB, GL_TRUE,
            WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB, WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB,
            WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB, 32,
            WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB, 24,
            WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB, 8,
            0 // End of attributes list
        };
        int iContextAttribs[] =
        {
            WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, iMajorVersion,
            WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, iMinorVersion,
            WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,
            0 // End of attributes list
        };
        int  iNumFormats;
        if(!wglChoosePixelFormatARB(hdc, iPixelFormatAttribList, NULL, 1, &pf, (UINT*)&iNumFormats)){
            MessageBox(NULL,"wglChoosePixelFormatARB","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP);
            return 0;
        }

        // PFD seems to be only redundant parameter now
        if(!SetPixelFormat(hdc, pf, &pfd)){
            MessageBox(NULL,"SetPixelFormat 2","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP);
            return false;
        }

        hrc = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(hdc, 0, iContextAttribs);
        // If everything went OK
        if(hrc) wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc);
        else bError = true;
        //glewInit();

    }else{
        bError = true;
    }
    if(bError)
    {
        // Generate error messages
        char sErrorMessage[255], sErrorTitle[255];
        sprintf(sErrorMessage, "OpenGL %d.%d is not supported! Please download latest GPU drivers!", iMajorVersion, iMinorVersion);
        sprintf(sErrorTitle, "OpenGL %d.%d Not Supported", iMajorVersion, iMinorVersion);
        MessageBox(hWnd, sErrorMessage, sErrorTitle, MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        return false;
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    MSG msg;
    progRun = true;

    ShowWindow(hWnd,SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    //-----------Setup shader and objects  
    setupShader();
    setupObject();
    //-------  
    glClearDepth(1.0f);                         // Depth Buffer Setup
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                        // Enables Depth Testing
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

    glClearColor(1,0,0,1);

    while(progRun){

        if (PeekMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)){
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        display();

        SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }



    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    switch (message){

    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        display();
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_SIZE: 
        glViewport(0, 0, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        progRun = false;
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which rectangle do you expect? You are not drawing anything in the display() method.

Comment: i didnt put all the code to make it eazier, since the problem is most likely one the win32 part. this the square GLfloat square Points [14] = {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1}

Comment: void display(){glUseProgram(shaderProg);
    glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0,4);}

Answer (score 0):

If you use `wglCreateContext` then you get **old** context (<= 2.1).

You need `wglCreateContextAttribsARB` instead. But this first you need to get a pointer to this function, which requires using a context.

So:

1. Create a normal, old context, and set it current. Any pixelformat is
   valid.
2. Get the pointers to `wglCreateContextAttribsARB` (and perhaps also  for `wglChoosePixelFormatARB`), by using
   `wglGetProcAddress`. Now you can delete the old context.
3. Set the pixelformat you wish and the context attributes you wish.
4. Create the context by that pointer.

Useful links from the [wiki OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Main_Page) are [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions#Windows_2) and  [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL)) and  [here](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tutorial:_OpenGL_3.1_The_First_Triangle_(C%2B%2B/Win))

Comment: Isn't that exactly what's being done in the question?

Comment: Has you can see above, i have done something like that, but it doesnt draw, do you have any full project using OpenGl with Win32 that you can show me.

Comment: @BDL Ah, yes. I missed `wglew.h` is included, and so pointers are retrieved.